# MySql tinyint using maximum display width parameter

Tags: mysql

MySql [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) states:

> M indicates the maximum display width for integer types.

I have:

```
CREATE TABLE `one` (x TINYINT(2));// set the display value to 2 digits

INSERT INTO `one` (x) VALUES (9);

SELECT * FROM `one`;
```

Output:

```
+------+
| x    |
+------+
|    9 |
+------+
```

Where is the two digit display width; I see a 4 digit width view as in:

```
+------+
| x    |
+------+
| 0009 |
+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The display width is a presentational hint to clients, which the command line client seems to ignore, and is free to do so.

The only time the display width is used by MySQL itself is when [`ZEROFILL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) is specified on the column - then an `int(4)` containing the value `684` will be retrieved as `0684`.

A lot more information can also be found [in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7552223/1729885), specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7552330/1729885) adds some extra.

Comment: The `ZEROFILL` option has no impact on the actual value stored for an integer type. The display width is most useful with the `ZEROFILL` options.

Comment: Corrected 'stored' to 'retrieved', thanks for the comment. This answer also got ninja-downvoted btw like yours, someone's on a roll.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you try adding a `NOT NULL` constraint on the column.

Note that a value of `NULL` in the column would be displayed as `NULL`, which (not oddly) requires 4 display characters.

```
INSERT INTO one VALUES (NULL);
SELECT * FROM one;

+------+
| x    |
+------+
|    9 |
| NULL |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

CREATE TABLE two (x TINYINT(2) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO two VALUES (9);
SELECT * FROM two;

+---+
| x |
+---+
| 9 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```