# How to change data type of a foreign key when its a primary key in another table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table `user_type` and `user_type_id` is the `primary key` of that table and I have another table `user_details` where `user_type_id` is `foreign key`.

I want to change data type of `user_type_id` column.

Comment: Using InnoDB I guess ?

Comment: from what type to what type. I recommend you copy as is to two work tables to play with it in a safe sandbox in case the `alter table` is lossy. It doesn't matter if the work tables have an FK setup at all on the first pass

Comment: i want change varchar to integer

Answer (score 16):

You must perform several steps.

On short: drop the foreign key, modify the fields user_type_id from varchar to int, re-create the foreign key.

It is very important to make back-ups before proceeding. That varchar to int conversion might mess-up the consistency if `user_type_id` values contain anything else that digits.

In detail:

1. First you need to drop the foreign key from `user_details`. To get the constraint name defining the foreign key run:

`SHOW CREATE TABLE user_details;`

You will see something like:

`CONSTRAINT 'some_constraint_name' FOREIGN KEY ('user_type_id') REFERENCES 'user_type' ('user_type_id')`

Delete that constraint by running

```
ALTER TABLE user_details DROP FOREIGN KEY some_constraint_name;
```

2. Now you can change `user_type_id` from varchar to int on both `user_type` and `user_details` tables:

`ALTER TABLE user_type CHANGE user_type_id user_type_id INT(length);`

`ALTER TABLE user_details CHANGE user_type_id user_type_id INT(length);`

Replace `length` with the old varchar field length.

3. Finally recreate the foreign key:

`ALTER TABLE user_details ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_type_id) REFERENCES user_type(user_type_id);`

Comment: This looks pretty good, but `length` does not do what you imply it does on `INT` columns.  That's "display width," a legacy feature from the green screen terminal days, a hint which most applications ignore.  The size of an integer is only determined by `TINYINT|SMALLINT|MEDIUMINT|INT|BIGINT` for 8, 16, 24, 32, and 64-bit values, respectively. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552223/int11-vs-intanything-else

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar scenario, the `mobo` column was of `CHAR(10)` datatype and wanted to convert it into `VARCHAR(16)` datatype.

I used below queries to for migrating the DB.

```sql
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
ALTER TABLE `user`
CHANGE `mobno` `mobno` varchar(16) COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' NOT NULL FIRST;
ALTER TABLE `staff`
CHANGE `mobno` `mobno` varchar(16) COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' NOT NULL AFTER `officeid`;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

The important note is to use `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` before running the queries and then again setting it back to 1 by running `SET foreign_key_checks = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

alter table `user_details` drop foreign key `nmFK`;

alter table `user_type` drop primary key, change `user_type_id` `user_type_id` [data type] not null, add primary key (`user_type_id`);

alter table `user_details` change `user_type_id` `user_type_id` [data type] not null;

alter table `user_details` add constraint `nmFK` foreign key (`user_type_id`) references `user_type`(`user_type_id`);

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: You should add explanation.