# Database structure for multiple locations of an organisation

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm creating an application using PHP (Codeigniter/MySQL) and within the application are organisations.

Each organisation can have multiple locations, regions, departments, etc (I'm calling these areas)

Each area has an administrator, and sometimes I will need to escalate things to a higher area.

I've currently got all the data in 1 table, and I am using a parent_area_id and area_level to determine the parents,children etc.

But I think this is very inefficient, and I've been pointed towards closure loops, which I have no knowledge of.

Here the database table, is this ok, will it be efficient or is there a better way to do it?

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| area_id        | int(12)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| area_title     | varchar(40) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| area_name      | varchar(40) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address1       | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address2       | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address3       | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| town           | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| county         | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| post_code      | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| has_ra         | varchar(1)  | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| org_id         | int(12)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| parent_area_id | int(8)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| area_level     | int(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

EDIT:

(better explanation of how this is being used)

1) Areas relate to customers of the business only.

2) The areas are different area(region,location,department) that a customer might have. (South region, Oxford Office, Accounts Dept).

3) Each area may have many employees allocated.

SO

If I had a regional administrator for example, they might have the following areas under them: e.g:

- South Region

  - Oxford office

    - Sales Department
    - Accounts Department
  - London Office

    - Marketing
    - Planning

SO

If I wanted to get the user_id's of all employees under the regional administrator, using the above database structure, i would need to:

1) Query the db to get all area_id's that have a parent_area_id of the regional administrator.

2) Loop through each returned area_id, and query the db and get all area_id's that have a parent_area_id of the returned area_id

3) Continue looping through returned area_id's until we get to the bottom level

4) Query the db to get all user_id's that have an area_id of all above returned records

SO

That doesn't seem very efficient, and needs multiple SQL queries and programming loops to get a list of users associated with a regional manager.

If thats the most efficient way to do it then fine I just don't seem convinced, and im sure there must be an easier way?

Comment: How did that end up with an `INT(12)` column? The default `INT` is `INT(11)`. Also concerning: the `INT(8)` for `parent_area_id`. Try and use plain old `INT` unless you have an extremely compelling reason not to. These minor differences can cause huge problems.

Comment: Thanks @tadman duly noted

Comment: Also worth noting: Most `_id` type fields require an index to be useful, as if there's an association there it's likely to be queried, and if it's to be queried you want it performant.

Comment: All my ID's have indexes? either PK or FK

Comment: `parent_area_id` doesn't have any indication in the Key column. This is why posting `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is usually better than `DESCRIBE`.

Comment: One cannot judge a schema without knowing what `SELECTs` will be applied to it.

Comment: org_id is a foreign key referencing a second table, correct?

Comment: One thing I would suggest is to move the address part (including town county etc.) to a separate table and reference it by fk. Rationale: even if I don't know what other entities you model, I believe you might need address for suppliers, sale agents, customers and/or employees. (Also it might be convenient in case you have to keep a history when an area moves to a different address).

Comment: I've added more detail to the question regading usage

Comment: fyi, `int(11)` vs `int(12)` has no relation to the amount  of space used in the database which is 4 bytes. The number in parenthesis is for display format only. maybe interesting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552223/int11-vs-intanything-else

Answer (score 2):

There's no serious problem here if you're dealing with a situation where you're escalating one level at a time. I've got no idea how "closure loops" would factor in here, that's programming related, not a database schema concern, and is largely a matter of personal preference.

So long as you don't violate the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of design, you should be okay. Your multiple address fields here skirt the line, that might be better represented as a single field that accepts multiple lines of text, but that is also how a lot of databases traditionally represent arbitrary street addresses.

Comment: I've edited the above question with more data on the usage

Comment: Your question's scope was already pretty broad, but this new edit makes it unreasonably open to interpretation. You'll have to try something and see what problems you encounter. It also sounds like you need to learn more about how a `JOIN` works since that can dramatically reduce the number of queries you need to do in a well-designed schema.