# MySQL: why are meaning of size inconsistent between int(size) and varchar(size)?

Tags: mysql, database

```
CREATE TABLE `features` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `feature_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

### For int(size)

size means display width, that is used when the field has ZEROFILL specified.

### For varchar(size)

the size means the max length(byte).

this parameter sometimes is used as display attribute, sometimes is used as storage limit. It's really confusing for web developer.

**why are they designed like this?**

**Is it because of historical reasons？**

### Reference

1. Stack Overflow: [int(11) vs. int(anything else)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552223/int11-vs-intanything-else)
2. Blog: https://alexander.kirk.at/2007/08/24/what-does-size-in-intsize-of-mysql-mean/

Comment: Because they're different things

Comment: Why are my shoes size 12 but my sweater size XXL?