# Difference between char(5) and int(5)

Tags: sql-server

Wanted to know the difference between char(5) and int(5). I know that char(5) should mean that field should be at the most 5 character long. But, what about int(5) ? Why is width needed for int ? Will it not throw error in case of int(width) as width is more than 4 ?

Also this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552223/int11-vs-intanything-else) says that int(width) is just the display length

Comment: There is no length specification for `int` in Microsoft SQL Server. The link in your question is for MySQL, an entirely different DBMS. In SQL Server char(5) is always fixed at 5 characters. varchar(5) is variable length, up to 5 characters. int is always 4 bytes. See the [data type documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql) for details.

Comment: That means int(width) should throw error ?

Comment: Yes, a length specification with int will raise is a syntax error in Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Yes `DECLARE @I int(5);` would cause an error.

Comment: was it so hard to try in SSMS?

Comment: It's also worth noting that an `int` (4 bytes) can hold a vastly larger number than a `char(4)` (also 4 bytes).

Comment: @CetinBasoz Realized it late, ie, after I posted the comment.

Comment: Pick your data types based on the *most natural representation*, not any purported benefits in terms of storage size. Is your data a number? That's the key question. And it's not answered by saying "yes, it only contains digits", or something like that. The question is, will you do maths with it? If yes, then pick a numeric data type (based on needed range, decimals, etc to pick which one). If not, and it happens to *contain* digits but not be a number (e.g. telephone), use a textual data type.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Wanted to clarify my doubt. I guess I got more confused by MySQL link, that said, in int(width) width is for display purpose. Thanks for your advice though.

Comment: Yes, but my point being is that, if you're correctly characterised your data, you should *never* come down to a choice between `char` and `int`.