# Why MariaDb seems to ignore parameter in `int(n)`?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

## The case:

**I tested this in mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.60-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)**

---

If I create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `some_table`(
  -- No matter what number I put in `int(n)`; the result is the same
  `id` int(1) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And I do this:

```
-- ID = 5 billion
INSERT INTO `some_table` VALUES('5000000000','the_name_is_irrelevant');
```

It inserts OK, **but fallbacking to the inherent limit of a `INTEGER UNSIGNED` type** (4 bytes). No matter what number I put into `int(n)` keyword when creating the table; the result is the same:

```
+------------+--------------------------+
|     id     |           name           |
+------------+--------------------------+
| 4294967295 | 'the_name_is_irrelevant' |   
+------------+--------------------------+
```

It seems that MariaDB ignores the numerical parameter when declaring an `int` field.

## The question:

How can this be? Is this just in `MariaDB`, or it also happens in `mysql`? Is there something I should know about what is that numerical parameter and what was it's original purpose (if it ever had one)?

Comment: Why are you inserting a numeric value as a varchar?

Comment: @The impaler: I had the hope it will allow me to dimension the `integer` type (without knowing if the units would be `cipher_qty` or `size_in_bytes`)...

Comment: The value 4294967295 is the maximum size of a unsigned int. The number specified when declaring the int column is only used for when it is being displayed and is not related to the value that may be stored in the column.

Comment: @SebasSBM Basically, that's only used for display purposes, not for deciding how large a value that field can hold. For your purposes, you might want to use BIGINT UNSIGNED (which ranges from 0 to 2^64-1) ([Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html))

Comment: @Dave --> I know. It is the inherent capacity of the default integer type unsigned (256**4) <-- (`**` = powered to)

Comment: When I try locally I get "Error: (conn:32) Out of range value for column 'id' at row 1
SQLState:  22003
ErrorCode: 1264" -- That makes sense since that number is too big for the column.

Comment: The max possible value for an `INT UNSIGNED` is 4294967295. So no, you can't store 5000000000.

Comment: @The Impaler. That is not the point of the question. I know what you say is true; the case I exposed in the question is just an experimental procedure to provide evidence. What trully annoys me is that, within `int(N)`, `N` seems to do nothing at all...

Comment: Oh, I see. That's the MariaDB/MySQL engine, allright. You need to understand it's a basic database engine that accepts a lot of SQL clauses **while ignoring them**. That's how it is. Don't expect high SQL compliance from MariaDB/MySQL. It's a great database don't get me wrong, but it's far behind PostgreSQL, Oracle, or DB2. When you accept that fact (and its price $), then it's OK.

Comment: @SebasSBM From the dupe link, use INT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL and use an ID of 1. When you then select from that table, what do you see?

Comment: Well, it seems the answer I was looking for is in the main answer of the question referenced in the "duplication mark" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7552317/3692177)... that said, perhaps I will auto-answer this duplicated question, to close the cycle...