# mysql tinyint(1) vs tinyint(2) vs tinyint(3) vs tinyint(4)

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySql: Tinyint (2) vs tinyint(1) - Which difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839927/mysql-tinyint-2-vs-tinyint1-which-difference)

What is the difference between:

- `TinyINT(1)`
- `TinyINT(2)`
- `TinyINT(3)`
- `TinyINT(4)`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

TinyINT(M) always has a range from -128..+127 signed or 0..255 unsigned. M is the display width.

> M indicates the maximum display width for integer types. The maximum
>   display width is 255. Display width is unrelated to the range of
>   values a type can contain, as described in Section 11.2, “Numeric
>   Types”. For floating-point and fixed-point types, M is the total
>   number of digits that can be stored.

from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html

Comment: Am I correct in guessing that the maximum display width being 255 is unrelated to the maximum value of an unsigned TINYINT also being 255? That's just a coincidence?

Comment: @NathanWailes yes. So realistically `TinyInt(3) unsigned` is sufficient to display the max _value_ of `255`. Whereas `TinyInt(4)` is need to display `-128` for instance.

Comment: display of what .. where..?. if i am writing a client app,or web app,  i only care about the value being retrieved, it's up to me how i format it / display it . yours confused.

Comment: The reference page in the answer is now missing and it's unable to edit it since there are too many pending edits. Please check [Mysql Data Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html) instead of it.

Answer (score 7):

According to [Mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html) all decimal numeric types supports syntax:

```
Integer Types (Exact Value)
```

When using `DECIMAL` it [allows you to specify precision](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html).

With `*INT` types it's [has mainly display function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) which also specifies how many places should be added when using `ZEROFILL`.

The byte size remains unaffected ([`1B` for `TINYINT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html#integer-types)).

Answer (score 3):

TinyINT = -128...+127

(n) is for display purposes.

Comment: @Fracois B. - What does it mean by "display purposes" ??

Comment: Display purposes, i.e., the actual character spacing length given to that column when you select from the table.

Comment: ... while using a console. For developers, ingesting SQL data into structures, the display-width value is meaningless.