# Spark JDBC SQLException

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-spark

I keep getting SQLException but I suspect that it is not the problem.
Table is :

```
create table person (first varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL, last varchar(30)      DEFAULT NULL, gender char(1) DEFAULT NULL, age tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL);
```

Insert statements:

```
insert into person values('Barack','Obama','M',54);
insert into person values('Hillary','Clinton','f',34);
```

Spark code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Stackoverflow")
                            .setMaster("local[4]");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
        Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
        options.put("url", "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/persondb");
        options.put("user", "user");
        options.put("password", "password333");
        options.put("dbtable", "(select * from person where gender = 'M') as someone");

        DataFrame jdbcDF = sqlContext.read().format("jdbc"). options(options).load();
        jdbcDF.show();
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.sql.SQLException: Out of range value for column 'age' : value age is not in Integer range
```

I tried changing table stmt(@jmj):

```
create table person (first varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL, last varchar(30)      DEFAULT NULL, gender char(1) DEFAULT NULL, age int DEFAULT NULL);
```

Then it worked for some queries but mostly it is giving:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Out of range value for column 'age' : value age is not in Integer range
```

Answer (score 2):

The source of your problem is the use of **TINYINT(4)** to storage the age.

Change the type by **INT** insead **TINYINT(4)**.

To understand why check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120904/mysql-tinyint1-vs-tinyint2-vs-tinyint3-vs-tinyint4).

Hope this Helps.