# What is the difference of tinyint(3) with tinyint(4) in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tinyit in mysql can take values from `0 - 257` unsigned.
So if your 100 is my max number, then I will have the type as `tinyint(3)`.

My question is what is the purpose of having `tinyint(4)` ? I mean there will be no 4 digits number in the `tinyint`.

Thank you

Comment: Probably another bit for the +/- (vs. the unsigned 3)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120904/mysql-tinyint1-vs-tinyint2-vs-tinyint3-vs-tinyint4

Comment: @ZiTAL to be honest I read that before posting but I didn't understand the core of the question since it is not in plain english

Comment: @Pashiamas read this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13120942/454827