# What is the meaning parameter TINYINT(parameter)?

Tags: mysql, database

I can not understand why this option. 
The signed TINYINT data type can store integer values between -128 and 127.

```
mysql> create table b (i tinyint(1));

mysql> insert into b values (42);

mysql> select * from b;
+------+
| i    |
+------+
|   42 |
+------+
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySql: Tinyint (2) vs tinyint(1) - Which difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839927/mysql-tinyint-2-vs-tinyint1-which-difference)

Answer (score 5):

Data-wise, `tinyint(1)`, `tinyint(2)`, `tinyint(3)` etc. are all exactly the same. They are all in the range -128 to 127 for `SIGNED` or 0-255 for `UNSIGNED`. As other answers noted the number in parenthesis is merely a display width hint.

You might want to note, though, that application=wise things may look different. Here, `tinyint(1)` can take a special meaning. For example, the Connector/J (Java connector) treats `tinyint(1)` as a boolean value, and instead of returning a numerical result to the application, it converts values to `true` and `false`. this can be changed via the `tinyInt1isBit=false` connection parameter.

A tinyint(1) can hold numbers in the range -128 to 127, due to the datatype being 8 bits (1 byte) - obviously an unsigned tinyint can hold values 0-255.

It will silently truncate out of range values:

```
mysql> create table a
    -> (
    ->    ttt tinyint(1)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into a values ( 127 );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into a values ( -128 );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into a values ( 128 );
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into a values ( -129 );
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from a;
+------+
| ttt  |
+------+
|  127 |
| -128 |
|  127 |
| -128 |
+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

... unless you change the `sql_mode` or change the server config:

```
mysql> set sql_mode=STRICT_ALL_TABLES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into a values ( -129 );
ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'ttt' at row 1
mysql>
```

The value used in the DDL for the datatype (eg: tinyint(1)) is, as you suspected, the display width. However, it is optional and clients don't have to use it. The standard MySQL client doesn't use it, for example.

***https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html***

***https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html***

***[MySql: Tinyint (2) vs tinyint(1) - what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839927/mysql-tinyint-2-vs-tinyint1-which-difference)***

Answer (score 2):

The lenght parameter for numeric data types only affect the display width, but not the value that can be stored.

```
TINYINT   -128 to 127 (or 0-255 unsigned)
SMALLINT  -32768 to 32767 (or 0-65535 unsigned)
MEDIUMINT -8388608 to 8388607 (or 0-16777215 unsigned)
INT       -2147483648 to 2147483647 (or 0-4294967295 unsigned)
BIGINT    -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807 (or 0-18446744073709551615 unsigned)
```