# More than 1 digit is displayed when using TINY(1) as the data type in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

I have a column in MySQL database which is defined as

> `IsDeleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'

in a table called `MyTable`.

According to the MySQL document [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html):

> M indicates the maximum display width for integer types. The maximum
>   display width is 255. Display width is unrelated to the range of
>   values a type can contain, as described in Section 11.2, “Numeric
>   Types”.

`M` in the above paragraph represents the `1` in `TINYINT(1)`.

I think this means that when I store the value `23`, which contains 2 digits, inside this column.

> `UPDATE MyTable SET IsDeleted=23 WHERE id = 1;`

I'll see `2` or `3` when I retrieve the value.

But I'm wrong. I see `SELECT IsDeleted FROM MyTable WHERE id = 1;` command generate `23` as the output.

Why does this happen? What's the meaning of `maximum display width`?

My MySQL version is `5.7.20`.

Comment: "maximum display width" --- is the column width used by mysql command line client. It is effectively useless number unless you're using it in a command line and have some specific use cases.

Comment: @zerkms If you have a documentation link for that, it would be helpful.  Or, you could post your own answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's just an observation, I believe it's up to the client on how to treat it. And I cannot find anything in the `mysql` cli client documentation :shrug:

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

Comment: _The `(m)` is ignored except when used with `ZEROFILL`_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The `(m)` is ignored except when used with `ZEROFILL`*

(That's all that need be said about the `(1)`.)

Answer (score 1):

The `(1)` in `TINYINT(1)` refers to the maximum display width, which is not the same as the precision of the field.

As the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) shows, `TINYINT`, along with the other integer types, is an exact type, and can store a range of values from -128 to 127 (if signed), or 0 to 255 (if unsigned).

So inserting 23 into a `TINYINT` column is legitimate.  But as [this demo](http://rextester.com/TJLS48066) shows, attempting to insert a value into a `TINYINT` column which is outside of the range mentioned above results in an error.

Answer (score 0):

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23112270/1785967) answer you can find a more exhaustive explanation of the difference between different values for the parameter of `TINYINT`, but the idea is that it is always one byte, therefore it can either store SIGNED values going from -128 to 127 or UNSIGNED ones from 0 to 255.