# Rails sees mysql tinyint(1) as a boolean - but I want it to be a number

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Rails 4.2.1 using mysql2 gem. ActiveRecord treats a mysql column with data type `tinyint(1)` as a boolean. But I want to use it as a small number - I want to store values up to 100 which is ok for `tinyint(1)`. When I try to create a record, the tinyint column casts to `false` and I get a depreciation warning:

```
> Foo.create(my_tinyint_col: 13)
  (0.2ms)  BEGIN
    SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO `foos` (`my_tinyint_col`) VALUES (0)
  (107.3ms)  COMMIT
  => #<Foo ID: 519, my_tinyint_col: false>
```

> DEPRECATION WARNING: You attempted to assign a value which is not
>   explicitly `true` or `false` to a boolean column. Currently this value
>   casts to `false`. This will change to match Ruby's semantics, and will
>   cast to `true` in Rails 5. If you would like to maintain the current
>   behavior, you should explicitly handle the values you would like cast
>   to `false`.

If i change the data definition of `my_tinyint_col` to `tinyint(2)` the problem goes away - but is there a way to treat `tinyint(1)` as a number using ActiveRecord?

Comment: Why fuss over every single byte? How many billions of records do you have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same issue occurs when `tinyint(1)` is seen as `boolean` by `Hibernate`. The trick is not to use `tinyint(1)` but to use `tinyint(4)`. Doing so, *RoR* won't assume that it is boolean.

At any rate, there is actually no difference between `tinyint(1)` and `tinyint(2)` in `MySQL`. Both can hold the same values - 1 and 2 are signifiers of `column width` only.

[See this please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839927/mysql-tinyint-2-vs-tinyint1-what-is-the-difference)

Answer (score 2):

For people who found this issue via google search: if you have the same problem but don't want to actually change the column data type you can add this line to your model.

```rb
attribute :my_tinyint_col, ActiveRecord::Type::Integer.new
```

Further reading: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thanks. After looking at those docs I've just tried `attribute :my_tinyint_col, :integer` and it works!