# In a Rails migration on a MySQL database, how to add a new column of type tinyint?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Ruby on Rails application backed by a MySQL database. I want to add a new column of the MySQL type `tinyint` to one of my existing database tables.

After creating a new ActiveRecord migration class (via the command-line generator `rails generate migration`), what's the syntax to use in my `add_column` method call in my `change` method to add the new `tinyint`-type column? That is:

```
class MyMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :my_existing_table_name, :my_new_column_name,  # Q: What goes here?
  end
end
```

Comment: What you answered is correct, but also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57485464/3935428) in case you still need AR to return this value as an integer and not a boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a value of `:boolean` for the `type` parameter in the `add_column` call. For example:

```
class MyMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :my_existing_table_name, :my_new_column_name, :boolean
  end
end
```

Reference: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_column