# In simplest of cases ODBC DataReader can't Get boolean value while data is correct

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, odbc, datareader

I am trying to read a `boolean` value from `ODBCDataReader` by using `ODBCDataReader.GetBoolean(i)` in theory it should work fine as the column we have read is a `boolean column` and the data coming in is either `1` or `0`

so when I read it like this -

```
return reader.IsDBNull(col) ? null : reader.GetBoolean(col);
```

I get `InvalidCastException`

Then I tried to fetch reader as

```
return reader.IsDBNull(col) ? null : Convert.ToBoolean(reader.GetValue(col));
```

The above line complains about `The string is not recognized as a valid bool value.`(value is "1")

Then I wrote the following method --

```
public static bool? GetDbSafeNullableBit(this IDataRecord reader, string propertyName, bool? defaultBool = null)
    {
        var returnValue = defaultBool;
        var col = reader.GetOrdinal(propertyName);
        if (reader.IsDBNull(col))
        {
            return returnValue;
        }

        var stringValue = reader[col].ToString();

        switch (stringValue)
        {
            case "1":
                returnValue = true;
                break;
            case "0":
                returnValue = false;
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception($"Value read from reader is not defined as proper boolean, value is {stringValue}");
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

and Voila, I find this works fine.

Can someone please guide me on why the first two ways are not giving the expected result.

PS: Data is coming from PostgresSql (makes any difference ?)

Comment: What is a data type of column? It can't cast int into boolean. You say, it has only "1 and 0", but user can not be trusted :) In my previous job we had to cast varchar into bool, so we had something like: case "true": case "1": case "yes": case "y": return true; break; Because admins kept putting stuff like this into this pure column.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ArkadiuszRaszeja, but probably you missed that I mentioned that we are tring to read value from a  `bit` column

Comment: The main difference between "boolean" and "bit" is that bit is literally one bit, but boolean is the shortcut for tinyint(1), so theoretically it could contain numbers other than 1 and 0. If you put 0 it will be aliased as "false" but every non-zero values are aliased as "true". That is why it is hard to cast them directly :(

Comment: if its just one bit it cant be anything but 1 or 0, if it tries to truncate a tinyInt it will still end up being 1 or 0, i have a strong feeling this has something to do with odbc as I have never encountered this error working with sqlDataReader

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but tinyint(1) is a normal tinyint with displaywidth = 1. So theoretically you can expect one byte to one bit conversion. (eg. 128 into one bit). Just guessing, not saying you are wrong :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839927/mysql-tinyint-2-vs-tinyint1-what-is-the-difference

Comment: Out of curiosity, why ODBC and why not NpgSql?  NpgSql handles so much more natively and even handles things like array datatypes and custom PostgreSQL data types.