# JOOQ: map tinyint to boolean based on its length

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

My current jooq-codegen-maven configuration maps all tinyint(1) fields to java's boolean values:

```xml
<forcedTypes>
    <forcedType>
        <name>BOOLEAN</name>
        <types>(?i:TINYINT)</types>
    </forcedType>
</forcedTypes>
```

Issue is that in some cases DB contains columns marked as tinyint(3) which should not be treated as boolean but some real int. Unfortunately I could not find any examples, docs have something but it didn't really worked for me:

```xml
<forcedType>
   <name>BOOLEAN</name>
   <types>TINYINT\(1\)</types>
</forcedType>
```

Comment: Note that even if this worked, your regular expression is escaped incorrectly. You meant to write `TINYINT\(1\)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Starting from jOOQ 3.12

We've implemented support for reading the numeric [display width](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40938860/521799) from MySQL in the code generator. You can match it using:

```sql
<forcedType>
  <name>BOOLEAN</name>
  <includeTypes>
    (?i:(TINY|SMALL|MEDIUM|BIG)?INT(UNSIGNED)?\(1\))
  </includeTypes>
</forcedType>
```

This is documented in this blog post:
https://blog.jooq.org/2019/09/27/how-to-map-mysqls-tinyint1-to-boolean-in-jooq/

This was implemented with: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7719

#### Until jOOQ 3.11

Prior to jOOQ 3.12, the jOOQ code generator did not consider the [display width](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40938860/521799) of types like `TINYINT` for the `<types/>` regular expression, simply because it reads only `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DATA_TYPE` (which doesn't contain this information), instead of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_TYPE` (which does).

If upgrading to 3.12 is not an option, you may either:

- Enumerate all your boolean types in that `<forcedType/>` specification
- Write a [programmatic code generator configuration](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-programmatic/) where you query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_TYPE` to generate the set of columns that need to be forced to type `BOOLEAN`