# Default value in sql laravel table

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, mariadb

I not sure if this is related to Laravel or not but I created the table with Laravel. I've got a table called `programmers`

```
DESC programmers;
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name         | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| age          | int(11)             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at   | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at   | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| framework_id | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| test         | tinyint(1)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

as you can see there's a column called `test` that's not nullable and has a default value of null. When I to run the following command from the database I expected an error

```
INSERT INTO  programmers (name, age, framework_id) VALUES ('Melly2', 19, 2)
```

it actually worked fine and here's the data

```
SELECT * FROM programmers;
+----+--------+-----+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+------+
| id | name   | age | created_at          | updated_at          | framework_id | test |
+----+--------+-----+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+------+
|  1 | melly  |  20 | 2022-05-03 16:36:12 | 2022-05-03 16:36:12 |            1 |    0 |
|  2 | Melly2 |  19 | NULL                | NULL                |            2 |    0 |
+----+--------+-----+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+------+
```

the `test` column actually defaulted to `0` not `null`, and if I were to run the following command it tells me I can't have null as a value as expected

```
INSERT INTO  programmers (name, age, framework_id, test) VALUES ('Melly2', 19, 3, null);
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'test' cannot be null
```

question: can someone briefly explain why `test` column didn't default to `null`?

Comment: Which MySQL/MariaDB version are you using?

Comment: Old MySQL versions had that odd behavior, but it has been fixed for years now.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/156159/field-both-not-null-and-default-null

Comment: as I understand this, "default set to null" means that you didn't set a default. If you don't enter data for that column, it defaults to the default for that data type, which for `tinyint` is 0.

Comment: No default value, and NOT NULL, means a value _has to be provided_. (However, early MySQL versions did not work that way.)

Comment: Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839927/mysql-tinyint-2-vs-tinyint1-what-is-the-difference

Comment: @Esther I think that explains it

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, the default value is `null` only if you don't provide a value. But when you provide some value, it should be compatible with the datatype you set for the column.

Here the datatype is `tinyint`. So, you should provide the values from true/false which infact will be converted into 1/0; else you should insert integers example:0,1,2,... etc.