# Wrong value insert while int length above 11 using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Continue from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892341/what-does-int5-in-mysql-mean) question ,

I have a table called customer_report id[int(11)],customer_id[int(5)] in Mysql 
while insertng values into the table the customer_id entered wrongly as 2147483647.

My query as below :

```
insert into customer_report (id,customer_id) 
values('','99999999999')
```

Whats wrong with this ?

Anyone help please .

Thank in advance.

Comment: You have to increase the length of `customer_id`.

Comment: change column int to bigint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please change the customer_id structure to `bigint` or do `int(11)`

Comment: I changed to bigint its solved but whats the problem why its not truncate the value as varchar when int(5) or int(11)

Comment: there is some range for integer

Comment: http://help.scibit.com/mascon/masconMySQL_Field_Types.html
your issue resolved? then accept the answer