# How to prevent SQL rounding PHP input values

Tags: php, mysql, rounding

I'm using the following PHP to insert a record into MySQL (I've reformatted the code to make it easier to read). In my database structure, product_cost is int(100), yet it rounds the value from 3.5 to 4. This also applies if I change product_cost to decimal(65)

```
$query = "INSERT INTO produce (
   farm_id, product, product_cost, mass, measurement
) VALUES ( 
   1, 'cheese', 3.50, 1, 'kg'
)";

$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
confirm_query($result);
```

Comment: integer has **no decimal places**. anything stored in an int must be rounded. you need either _float_, for general purpose-stuff, or _decimal_ with the right amount of decimal places configured - in your case DECIMAL(65,2) - which is mostly used for currencies. see also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html .

Comment: use DOUBLE or Float type with the wanted precision instead of INT

Comment: side note, stop using `mysql_*`

Comment: `DECIMAL(65,2)` or something?

Comment: try change product_cost to decimal(65,2) (how many numbers after ",")

Comment: for meaning of (100) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892341/what-does-int5-in-mysql-mean

Comment: you're fitting a square peg in a round hole

Comment: I tried DECIMAL(65, 2) but it automatically becomes DECIMAL(65, 0) and the issue still occurs

Comment: "The maximum number of digits for DECIMAL is 65," (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html) so thats' why, 65 seems massive for your example

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Just use `DECIMAL(8,2)`. That should be more than enough digits for your `product_cost` (it will support a price up to `$999,999.99`)

Answer (score 0):

use the `DECIMAL`data type in mysql if you dont want your numbers as a round figure. with the parameters of `20,2` or `65,2`