# int(size), what is size here?

Tags: sql, mysql

> int(size) = A medium integer. Signed range is from -2147483648 to 2147483647. Unsigned range is from 0 to 4294967295. The size parameter specifies the maximum display width (which is 255) [[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp)]

I didn't understand that the maximum value that I can pass in int field of MySQL database is 4294967295, then what is 255, and if it's actually a width of a number that I can pass in int field, so definitely it will be a larger no. than the max range value,so logically it is not possible to save in database.

Somewhere I read that size is the display width which is used only at a time of displaying the data and we can assign zeros in the front of the data to make it equal size of int's parameter size, so again the question arises why we are doing this rubbish.

And I also read int is 4 bytes no matter what is the length of the number. It also signifies that 255 is not the size in bytes.
THEN WHAT 255 IS ?

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892341/what-does-int5-in-mysql-mean?

Comment: Great! It's having a right solution.

Comment: The display size is used together with ZEROFILL to left pad numbers. For example a column set to 
INT(5) ZEROFILL and a row value of 12 will show as 00012.