# Auto delete MySQL records relating tags to bookmarks with a middle table connecting them using Foreign Keys?

Tags: php, mysql

My MySQL app allows users to create `bookmarks` and organize them with `tags`.

A `tag` is added to a `bookmark` with a middle MySQL DB table `bookmark_tag_relationship`

I would like to add a `Foreign Key` to auto-delete all records in `bookmark_tag_relationship` when a `Bookmarks` record is deleted.

All the `bookmark_tag_relationship` records deleted would have a `bookmark_id` column that matches the `id` column on the bookmark record that is deleted

How can I set this up correctly based on the 3 table structures shown below?

**Failed attempt #1**

I tried something like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE bookmarks ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES bookmark_tag_relationship(`bookmark_id`);
```

It returned an error with no information just that it could not create it.

---

**table bookmarks**

```sql
--
-- Table structure for table `bookmarks`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookmarks` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `url_id` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `favicon_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `project_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `github_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `demo_url` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `local_demo_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image4` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `notes` text,
  `tags_string` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `click_count` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tag_count` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_viewed_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**table tags**

```sql
--
-- Table structure for table `tags`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `color` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bookmark_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**table bookmark_tag_relationship**

```sql
--
-- Table structure for table `bookmark_tag_relationship`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookmark_tag_relationship` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bookmark_id` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(30) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: *Hm....*, probably one or all of those tables needs an AI'd or primary key and none show as being AUTO_INCREMENT assigned anywhere. only `int(x) NOT NULL,` and then you have `AUTO_INCREMENT=5`. I.e: from the manual `id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html unless I'm wrong about this.

Comment: Is the table empty for starters?

Comment: I don't think Innodb will auto increment a column if it is not a primary key or index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three issues:

- You have not defined a primary key in the table bookmarks (or any other);
  In comments you clarified you actually have them, so then this is a non-issue;
- You have the foreign key constraint defined in the opposite direction. You should define it on the child table;
- You need to add the `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause.

So, execute this, and it will work (you can skip the first one, since in comments you clarified you already have the primary key):

```sql
ALTER TABLE bookmarks ADD
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY(id);

ALTER TABLE bookmark_tag_relationship
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (bookmark_id)
    REFERENCES bookmarks(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Now you can delete a bookmark, for example:

```sql
DELETE FROM bookmarks WHERE id = 1;
```

...and the related records in *bookmark_tag_relationship* will be deleted in the same transaction.

#### Some additional remarks:

- The difference between `int(20)` and `int(30)` that you have for the primary key and foreign key types cannot be very useful. It does not influence the constraint, but I would still suggest to harmonise that as follows:

```sql
    ALTER TABLE bookmark_tag_relationship 
        MODIFY bookmark_id int(20) NOT NULL;
```

- It is not needed to surround your table and column names with backticks. Only when you have chosen reserved words for those names, they are needed, but that is something you'd want to avoid anyway.

Comment: Your foreign key query will fail because his bookmark_id column in the bookmark_tag_relationship table is an INT(30).

Comment: I know the types are different, but it doesn't fail: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/372a3. The docs also say they can be slightly different. It seems version dependent. On 5.7 it is like you say. The int types must have same size.

Comment: I just tried it locally on Sequel Pro and it failed with **Cannot add foreign key constraint**.

Comment: I just updated my comment. It seems version dependent.

Comment: It's not failing in your sqlfiddle because they are both INT(10). Click on BROWSER and you'll see their types.

Comment: **Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar data types. The size and sign of integer types must be the same.** From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! So 10 is maximum size anyway? or is that a sql fiddle "feature"?

Comment: No problem! SQLFiddle is limiting it to 10 apparently.

Comment: Thanks and also all the tables have a primary index on there ID I just forgot to post the export SQL of that

Comment: INT(10) is NOT a different data size the INT(3)  Please read and understand the INT type in MySQL

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562322/difference-between-int-and-int3-data-types-in-my-sql

Comment: Thanks @JoeSwindell, I completely misunderstood that notation. Honestly, it is very misleading, and now that I understand it is about display, I don't think it belongs in the SQL language at all. Thanks again.

Comment: @trincot yeah it's one of the few things I hate about MySQL. When I stumbled across that one day I was mind blown.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: You're foreign key is also failing because you do not have a primary key. A foreign key is a reference to a primary key.

I would setup a trigger for bookmarks on delete.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`username`@`%` TRIGGER `bookmarks_ADEL` AFTER DELETE ON `bookmarks` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM bookmark_tag_relationship WHERE bookmark_id = old.id;
END
```

When a row from Bookmarks is deleted, it will take that ID and remove the row out of bookmark_tag_relationship.

You need to set Primary keys in both those tables, most likely the ID

One note about using a cascade delete on foreign key. It will not activate any triggers that are set on those deleted rows. So as you progress, if you decide to trigger off them to remove or modify more information, the foreign key cascade will not activate them and you'll have to trigger on delete anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a ON DELETE CASCADE on your foreign key.

```
ALTER TABLE bookmark_tag_relationship ADD FOREIGN KEY (`bookmark_id`) 
REFERENCES bookmarks(`id`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: In fact, it is an answer. Try to make it look nice, and quote the original statement.

Comment: I'm not sure the right syntax now, this is the best I can do now. When i get home, i do it better. Thanks for the advice

Comment: It should be the other way around. He wants the bookmark_tag_relationship to reference the bookmark table. Not the bookmarks table referencing the bookmark_tag_relationship.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few reasons why your foreign key is not working.

First of all, you need to make sure the column **id** of each table is a **primary key**.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD PRIMARY KEY (table_column)
```

After you've added your primary key, you need to make sure that their type is the same.

In your **bookmark_tag_relationship** table, the bookmark_id is **INT(30)**, but in your **bookmarks* table, your column 'id' is **INT(20)**. You need to make sure both of them are the same. So either change the id from bookmarks to INT(30) or change the other one to INT(20).

And at last, your foreign key query is reversed. You want it the other way around.

```
ALTER TABLE bookmark_tag_relationship ADD FOREIGN KEY (`bookmark_id`)      
REFERENCES bookmarks(`id`)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

You want the bookmark_tag_relationship to be deleted when a bookmark is deleted, and not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Use a primary auto incremented key on the id columns.  And then like others said use cascade on delete with foreign keys.

```
mysql> show create table bookmarks\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: bookmarks
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `bookmarks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table tags\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: tags
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table bookmarks_tags\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: bookmarks_tags
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `bookmarks_tags` (
  `bookmark_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`bookmark_id`,`tag_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `bookmarks_tags_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`bookmark_id`) REFERENCES `bookmarks` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from bookmarks;
+----+-----------+
| id | title     |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | bookmark1 |
|  2 | bookmark2 |
|  3 | bookmark3 |
+----+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from tags;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | tag1 |
|  2 | tag2 |
|  3 | tag3 |
|  4 | tag4 |
|  5 | tag5 |
+----+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from bookmarks_tags;
+-------------+--------+
| bookmark_id | tag_id |
+-------------+--------+
|           1 |      1 |
|           1 |      2 |
|           1 |      3 |
|           2 |      1 |
|           2 |      4 |
|           3 |      5 |
+-------------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete from bookmarks where title = 'bookmark1';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from bookmarks; select * from tags; select * from bookmarks_tags;
+----+-----------+
| id | title     |
+----+-----------+
|  2 | bookmark2 |
|  3 | bookmark3 |
+----+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | tag1 |
|  2 | tag2 |
|  3 | tag3 |
|  4 | tag4 |
|  5 | tag5 |
+----+------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

+-------------+--------+
| bookmark_id | tag_id |
+-------------+--------+
|           2 |      1 |
|           2 |      4 |
|           3 |      5 |
+-------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: oops i forgot the foreign key for the join table and the tags table.  but that can be added just don't add delete on cascade to that one.